# tvOS app doesn't play audio file

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioplayer, tvos

I have a tvOS app which attempts to play an audio file like this:

```
#import "NameViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface NameViewController ()

@end

@implementation NameViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

    [player play];


}
```

If I put a breakpoint after [player play]; it starts playing for a few seconds.  If I don't have the breakpoint, no audio ever plays.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by calling play in viewWillAppear:

```
#import "NameViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface NameViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation NameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createAndStartAudioPlayer];


}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.player play];
}

- (void) createAndStartAudioPlayer {
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:nil];
    self.player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but since you said putting a break point after `[player play];` will cause audio to play, it sounds as if the system is trying to create and play the audio player too fast...are you running this on a simulator or on the TV dev kit?

Perhaps try adding a separate method for creating and playing the player, like so, will give the system enough time to create the view and *then* create and play the audio player?

```
- (void) createAndStartAudioPlayer {
  NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

    [player play];
}
```

And then calling that from `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self createAndStartAudioPlayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AVAudioPlayer needs to be defined as a property in your ViewController, you can then call it from where you want.

Answer (score 0):

The AVAudioPlayer is being deallocated before the sound finishes playing.  When you set a breakpoint after calling play, the audio player isn't deallocated until you continue so the sound keeps playing.  If you make the audio player a property like: `@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;` then it won't be deallocated until after your view controller is removed.